# comparing numbers in 2 string A and B

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x, compare

I am solving a problem in python.

I have 2 strings with numbers and I need to find out whether a number from string B is located in a string A.

for example:

```
a = "5, 7" 
b = "6,5"
```

A and B may contain any number and quantity.

If the number of string B is in A I want result true or false.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Are the numbers integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have strings, not integers, so you'd have to convert them to integers first:

```
a_nums = [int(n) for n in a.split(',')]
b_nums = [int(n) for n in b.split(',')]
```

This uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to turn each result of a [`str.split()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) call into integers with the [`int()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

To test if there are numbers in both sequences, you'd use [*sets*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), then test if there is an intersection:

```
set(a_nums) & set(b_nums)
```

If the result is not empty, there were numbers shared between the sequences. Since non-empty sets [are considered 'true'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), in Python, you'd convert this to a boolean with [`bool()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool):

```
bool(set(a_nums) & set(b_nums))
```

Sets are by far the most efficient method to test for such intersections.

You can do all this in one line, and a little more efficiently, with generator expressions and the [`set.intersection()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
bool(set(int(n) for n in a.split(',')).intersection(int(n) for n in b.split(',')))
```

or perhaps a little more compact still with the `map()` function:

```
bool(set(map(int, a.split(','))).intersection(map(int, b.split(','))))
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = "5, 7" 
>>> b = "6,5"
>>> bool(set(map(int, a.split(','))).intersection(map(int, b.split(','))))
True
```

or breaking it down a little:

```
>>> [int(n) for n in a.split(',')]
[5, 7]
>>> [int(n) for n in b.split(',')]
[6, 5]
>>> set(map(int, a.split(',')))
set([5, 7])
>>> set(map(int, a.split(','))).intersection(map(int, b.split(',')))
set([5])
>>> bool(set(map(int, a.split(','))).intersection(map(int, b.split(','))))
True
```

Answer (score 3):

If the numbers are integers, to obtain a list of `True` / `False` entries corresponding to whether each number in `b` is in `a`, try:

```
a = "5, 7" 
b = "6,5"
A = [int(x) for x in a.split(',')]
B = [int(x) for x in b.split(',')]
c = [x in A for x in B]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[False, True]
```

To find out if *any* of the numbers in `b` are in `a`, then:

```
any(c)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: I want only 1 result = I do not compare 6 with 5 and 5 with 7, but 6 with 5 and 7

Comment: This solution does that: for example, it would return `[True, True]` if `b="7,5"`

Answer (score 1):

```
#This should do the trick
a_ints = [int(i) for i in a.split(',')]
b_ints = [int(i) for i in b.split(',')]
for item in b_ints:
    for items in a_ints:
        if item==items: return true
return false
```